# How to merge two dates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

I have 2 date objects. I want to take the date from one and the time from the other and combine them into a new date object.

```
date.toString() = Wed Dec 21 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
time.toString() = Sun Dec 31 2000 03:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)

# I want to end up with
datetime.toString() = Wed Dec 21 2011 03:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

How can I best accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need more information than [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
var datetime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 
                        time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds());
```

Comment: Note that `getYear` is deprecated and should be switch to `getFullYear`.  Also, `getDay` returns the day of the week and should be switched to `getDate`.

Comment: As far as I get that, this solution does not account for daylight savings-time?

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this:

```
var year  = date.getFullYear(),
    month = date.getMonth(),
    day   = date.getDate();

time.setFullYear(year);
time.setMonth(month);
time.setDate(day);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var parts = ['Hours', 'Minutes', 'Seconds', 'Milliseconds'];
for (var i=0, p; p=parts[i], i<parts.length; i++) {
  date['setUTC'+p]( time['getUTC'+p]() );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use string functions to build the target string...

```
datetime = date.toString().substr(0,16) + time.toString().substr(16,40)
```

then if you need to have it as a date object, feed it into a `new date()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var msPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var newDateTime = new Date(date.getTime() + (time.getTime() % msPerDay));
```

EDIT: mine assumes date variable is a date without any time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best, but you can try the following:

```
datetime = new Date(
  date.getUTCFullYear(),
  date.getUTCMonth(),
  date.getUTCDate(),
  time.getUTCHours(),
  time.getUTCMinutes(),
  time.getUTCSeconds()
);
```

For further reference on the `Date` object look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: did not work for me - broke the TZ and messed up the time

Comment: @Kuf can you be a little more specific and maybe give an example?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  If it's very different from what the OP is asking you should consider starting / asking your own question.

Comment: I left this comment as a warning. in your code, you take local time, then convert it to UTC, then storing it again as local, which messes the TZ. I did resolve it by omitting the `UTC` from each function name (like @pna answer). hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using regexp to replace the time in date and then create the new Date object.

```
dateTime = new Date(date.toString().replace(/(\d\d:){2}\d{2}/,/(\d\d:){2}\d{2}/.exec(time.toString())[0]));
```