# javascript date & time join

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have two date variable separately like following

`startDate` is a `Date` instance with the value `Tue Jul 17 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`

`startTime` is a `String` with the value `"11:30 AM"`

Now what I need is join of both above date & time, as a `Date`.

`startDateTime` =  `Tue Jul 17 2012 11:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`

I tried

`new Date(startDate + " " + startDate)` but outputting `invalid date`.

Also tried the way shown on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423963/how-to-merge-two-dates-in-javascript). But still not working.

Comment: Have you tried date.js javascript library? It can convert/parse a lot of date formats.

Comment: Are `startDate` and `startTime` strings?

Comment: @JonasT, or [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which I prefer.

Comment: moment.js has the advantage of having been maintained in the last few years, which DateJS has not.

Comment: @lucero - `startTime` is string indeed. While `startDate` is date format.

Comment: @RikeshShah, so either use one of the JS libraries or parse the time yourself into milliseconds, which can easily be added to the dates value.

Comment: @RikeshShah: To improve a question, use the "edit" link underneath it. I've done that for you on this occasion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can readily parse `startTime` if it's in a clearly-defined format, then use `setHours` and `setMinutes`: [Live example](http://jsbin.com/uzayuq) | [source](http://jsbin.com/uzayuq/edit)

```
var startDateTime;
var parts = /^(\d+):(\d+) (AM|PM)$/.exec(startTime);
if (parts) {
    hours = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
    minutes = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
    if (parts[3] === "PM" && hours !== 12) {
        hours += 12;
    }
    else if (parts[3] === "AM" && hours === 12) {
        hours = 0;
    }
    if (!isNaN(hours) && !isNaN(minutes)) {
        startDateTime = new Date(startDate.getTime());
        startDateTime.setHours(hours);
        startDateTime.setMinutes(minutes);
    }
}
```

...or something along those lines.

Note that key to this is the fact you've said `startDate` is a `Date` instance. The above assumes we're working within the timezone of the JavaScript environment, not across zones. If you were starting with a date *string* instead, and that string specified a timezone other than the JavaScript environment's timezone, which you were then converting into a `Date` via `new Date("Tues Jul....")`, then you'd have to be sure to adjust the resulting `Date` to use either the local time of the environment, or UTC; if you adjusted it to be UTC, you'd use `setUTCHours` and `setUTCSeconds` above instead of `setHours` and `setSeconds`. Again, this is only an issue if your starting point is a date *string*, and that string specifies a timezone *different* from the timezone in which the code above is running.

Comment: Thanks !! Working perfectly :)

Comment: @RikeshShah: You may have to adjust it slightly if the `AM` / `PM` might be in lower case, etc., but that's the gist. But do check out moment.js.

Comment: @Crowder - I will take of it. And the moment I can't add any js in existing source.

Comment: This code won't work because of the timezone. The timestamp which you have to *add* the hours & minutes is actually Jul 16 2012, 20:30:00 UTC

Comment: @Bergi: It's fine, [`setHours`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.34) and `setMinutes` work within the timezone, and all `Date` objects in the same JavaScript execution environment share the same timezone ("local" time). If I'd used [`setUTCHours`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.35)/`setUTCMinutes`, now that would be a problem. :-)

Comment: Yes, it is a problem, because GMT+0530 is *not my* local timezone.

Comment: @Bergi: Right. But remember, Rikesh's starting point is a `Date` instance and a time string, not a date *string* and a time string. If we were working with a date *string*, and that string specified a timezone other than the environment's time zone, that would be a problem. But we're not. So the code will behave correctly in all timezones, because we're only working within the timezone of the environment, not across zones. It's not my timezone either (I'm currently in GMT+0100). But the linked example works fine.

Comment: For me, your code called with `new Date("Tue Jul 17 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530")` and `"11:30 AM"` results in `2012-07-16T09:30:00 UTC` (+2 hours for local time) - OK, when the OP had instantiated his `startDate` with local time, it would work.

Comment: @Bergi: Key to this is that Rikesh said `startDate` is a `Date` instance, not a string. (He said it in a comment, which I then edited into the question; some eejit has edited it out again, which I'll go fix.) So yes, `new Date("Tues ...")` will not work (if the string specifies a different timezone than the environment). But that's not the problem we're solving here.

Comment: Yes, I got that, only I thought he would instantiate it with a non-local time string.

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks. I added a paragraph to call that out, in case someone doing that finds this answer and gets the wrong idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can do This:

```
var theDate = new Date("Tue Jul 17 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)");
var theTime = "11:30 AM";
var hours = theTime .substr(0,2);
var minutes = theTime .substr(3,2);
var amOrPm = theTime .substr(6,2);
if (hours < 12 && "PM" == amOrPm) {
    hours = +hours + 12;
}
theDate.setHours(hours);
theDate.setMinutes(minutes);
```

Comment: This results in 2012-07-16T11:30:00, the correct timestamp would be 2012-07-17T07:00:00 (both UTC)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
new Date(startDate.toDateString() + " " + startTime)
```

This combines the date string from your `Date` object with the time string, and should give you a valid date. Note that this *ignores the timezone* you initially worked with, you might need to add `" GMT+0530"` again.

However, because your date string is already timezone-biased (Jul 16 2012, 20:30:00 UTC) it might be better to add them together, i.e. like `new Date(+startDate + milliseconds)`:

```
var startDate = new Date("Tue Jul 17 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530");
var startTime = "11:30 AM";
return new Date(+startDate + +new Date("1 1 1970 "+startTime))
```

Comment: Does it? Which values have you used, what string passed to the constructor? Works for me.